# Long Execution Time for dotnet restore in OpenShift Build Pipeline

Tags: .net, .net-core, devops, openshift, cicd

During our build pipeline execution on OpenShift, we've encountered a significant delay specifically with the dotnet restore command in the Dockerfile. This delay is causing notable slowdowns in our overall build process.

**My Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
ARG HTTP_PROXY="<my-url-local-proxy>"
ENV DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.API/My.API.csproj", "My.API/"]
COPY ["My.Application/My.Application.csproj", "My.Application/"]
COPY ["My.Infrastructure/My.Infrastructure.csproj", "My.Infrastructure/"]
COPY "My.API/nuget.config" .

RUN dotnet restore -v diag "./My.API/./My.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/My.API"
RUN dotnet build "./My.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./My.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.API.dll"]
```

**My nugget.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

#### Version

I'm using openshift version 4.

###### Current Result

- Local result: I can work fine with my Dockerfile in my local.
- OpenShift result: The dotnet restore operation consistently takes 1-hour duration and seems to time out during the MSBuild within our OpenShift build pipeline.

###### Additional Information

- I saw a make sense information about NuGet signed-package verification https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13062 and additional `ENV DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false` in Dockerfile. But it didn't resolve yet.

  - You also need it for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/nuget-signed-package-verification
- In my Dockerfile I also add a Proxy variable and use nuget.config file. You can look at it above.
- I tried to create another Node simple application image. But it also stuck on the `npm install` step. I think the same concept with the `dotnet restore` command.
- I'm always looking at my resource quota. I don't see CPU, memory,... reach limit
- I also tried to change  `aspnet:8.0` to `aspnet:7.0`. It still didn't success

Any insights or guidance will be expected. Thank you for your attention to this matter.